# Getting power of a music played in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, audio

I'm desperately searching how to get the power of a sound played via the iPod/Music app in my application.

Everything I was able to find was about getting the power of a sound via the microphone, or playing a sound in my own app via an AVAudioPlayer and then use the averagePowerForChannel: method.
I also searched if the MPMusicPlayerController could help me but the closest I get from what I want is the MPMediaItem of the "nowPlayingItem", and it seems that I can access a lot of informations from the currently played song but nothing like the current power.

Is there any way to simply get the current power of a song played from the Music app in my app ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Larme's answer is deprecated with iOS 7 (the `volume` attribute of `MPMusicPlayer` and the `iPodMusicPlayer` method). Try this instead to get an `AVAudioPlayer` instance with the current song (however, when I do mine, for some odd reason, it always returns `-120 dB`):

```
AVAudioPlayer *somePlayer = [AVAudioPlayer new];
__autoreleasing NSError* error;
somePlayer = [somePlayer initWithContentsOfURL:[[[MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer] nowPlayingItem] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL] error:&error];
somePlayer.currentTime = [[MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer] currentPlaybackTime];
somePlayer.volume = 0;
[somePlayer play];
[somePlayer setMeteringEnabled:YES];
[somePlayer updateMeters];
NSMutableArray* amps = [NSMutableArray array];
if (error != nil) {
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error.debugDescription);
}
for (int i = 0; i < somePlayer.numberOfChannels; i++) {
    [amps addObject:@(([somePlayer peakPowerForChannel:i] + 160.0) / 160.0)];
    NSLog(@"Amplitude: %f db for channel %i", [somePlayer averagePowerForChannel:i], i);
}
float amp = 0;
for (NSNumber *x in amps) {
    amp += [x floatValue];
}
amp /= amps.count;
NSLog(@"amp: %f", amp);
```

Comment: I am not working on this project anymore for years now so I'm not sure that your answer works (Larme's answer get the volume, and not the power as AlexChaffee commented), but this seems to be the kind of things I was looking for at the time so I'll accept it anyway.
Hope you'll help somebody else with this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this : `myPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];`

You can get the volume with `myPlayer.volume`.
It's a float. A step is 1/16.

Comment: That's volume, not power. Power is the moment-by-moment level, the thing you'd see on a decibel meter. (If power is 0, then no sound comes out, no matter what the volume.)

Comment: Volume is now deprecated